# Laravel 5.0 Route Model Binding didn't work in destroy action

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-form

I have a Form with one submit button and set the action to destroy method in a controller. The same code worked for other form and controller, but not working for this one. The action in form tag is wrong when I inspect my web page in Chrome.

This is my Form :

```
{!! Form::model($company, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Setting\Organization\CompaniesController@update', 'files'=>true, $company->CompanyCode]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('CompanyCode', 'Company Code : ', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3']) !!}
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            {!! Form::text('CompanyCode', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => true]) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::submit('Update Company', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'btnSubmit']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::model($company, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => 'Setting\Organization\CompaniesController@destroy', $company->CompanyCode]) !!}

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::submit('Delete Company', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The Update button works fine.

I access this form via edit method in Setting\Organization\CompaniesController :

```
public function edit(Company $company){
    return view('setting.organization.company.edit', compact('company'));
}
```

Here's destroy method in Setting\Organization\CompaniesController :

```
public function destroy(Company $company){
    dd($company);
    //------------ delete company
    $company->IsActive = 0;
    $company->update();

    flash()->info('Company ' . $company->Name . ' has been deleted.');
    return redirect('company');
}
```

The `dd($company);` line doesn't even work because the form didn't link to the right route.

The RouteServiceProvider file :

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('client', function($id){
        return \App\Models\Setting\ClientAccount::getClientFromAccountName($id);
    });

    $router->bind('company', function($id){
        return Company::getCompanyFromCode($id);
    });

}
```

.

.

This is the inspect element of the Form :

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/hrmsystem/public/company/%7Bcompany%7D" accept-charset="UTF-8" com160202145801="COM160202145801">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="B2luMsN5Oy81GUFLoUCoHc2ERnqHe1AYir1DEY4N">

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete Company">
    </div>

</form>
```

.

.

After I submitted the form :

[image: Error after submitting the form]

I understand that the error is ModelNotFoundException because the passed CompanyCode is %7Bcompany%7D. But I don't know where is it come from.

I use `Route::resource` in the routes.php.

Please help, I'm new to laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey its depend on your routing 
if you use  `Route::resource('companies','CompaniesController');` its easy for you no need to trouble just you can use your button like this

```
 {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('companies.destroy',  $company->CompanyCode))) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit('DELETE', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs')) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

if you want use your way then you have to use your form like this

```
{!! Form::open('method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['Setting\Organization\CompaniesController@destroy', $company->CompanyCode]) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::submit('Delete Company', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but didn't work, the error is still the same. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @Hamel, I use your first solution (using routes instead of action) and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, you saved my day :D

Comment: :) :) :) Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the action in the form tag is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
{!! Form::model($company, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'action' => ['Setting\Organization\CompaniesController@update', $company->CompanyCode],
    'files'=>true
]) !!}
```

The mistake was including `'files' => true` inside the action array since it's not a part of the action. It is its own attribute so it should be separate from the action array / outside of it.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's not the problem here since the problem is with the other Form (in my post I wrote 2 Forms in the same page). And it's true that I use File Upload in my first form, but I didn't wrote it in the post since the first form is working just fine. Can you help me?

Comment: I already fixed my error using @Hamel solution. Thanks for your time answering my question :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't use model bind for the DELETE

```
{!! Form::open('method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['Setting\Organization\CompaniesController@destroy', $company->CompanyCode]) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::submit('Delete Company', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Hi @Elias, I tried your solution but it didn't work for me, the error is still the same since the action in Form tag in Chrome inspect element is still the same with the one I posted. Please help.

Comment: I already fixed my error using @Hamel solution. Thanks for your time answering my question :D